# CredUIPromptForCredentials forcing manual selection of user name

Tags: c#, .net, windows, credentials

I am using [CredUIPromptForCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to prompt the user for credentials which are then passed to a web service.

The prompt shows the "Remember my password" option, so that User Name and Password can be populated with previously used values.

When the prompt appears and the credentials are pre-filled, I can't proceed until I actually select the User Name from the drop-down.

This is the screen I am seeing:

[image]

Clicking OK does nothing but bring up the Examples tip, but if I manually select "Greg" from the drop-down, I am able to proceed.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
StringBuilder userPassword = new StringBuilder(), userID = new StringBuilder();
CREDUI_INFO credUI = new CREDUI_INFO();
credUI.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(credUI);
bool save = true;
CREDUI_FLAGS flags = CREDUI_FLAGS.ALWAYS_SHOW_UI | CREDUI_FLAGS.GENERIC_CREDENTIALS 
                    | CREDUI_FLAGS.SHOW_SAVE_CHECK_BOX ;

//Display password prompt:
CredUIReturnCodes returnCode = CredUIPromptForCredentials
    (ref credUI, this.serverName, IntPtr.Zero, 0, userID, 100, userPassword, 100, ref save, flags);
```

OS is Windows 7 and Server 2008 r2.

I have created a complete but simple sample application which can be downloaded from https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxSAZ9JlU2w9VHZWWFBjVEhTNG02N1Q4WkFrUkhDUQ for testing.

Comment: i think its not saving the password

Comment: by changing password every run im able to logged in

Comment: @RaghuveerGuthikonda: the sample app assumes the password is correct - it should let you proceed regardless of the password you enter.

Comment: I pressed Cancel and it still thinks its authenticated.

Comment: @softwareisfun you know this is a question right?

Comment: @GregSansom how did you solve that? No matter what the user does, it's always returning as authenticated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `save = false` solves the problem.

The checkbox will not be checked by default, but if it is checked the password will be saved allow the user will be able to proceed without changing input values on subsequent attempts.

Answer (score 5):

I was going to attempt to answer your question, but you solved it yourself too quickly.

However, in reading the documentation on [CredUIPromptForCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I notice that you are recommended to use [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows 7 and Server 2008.

In Googling around I found this excellent [free class library](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) which contains wrappers for several native APIs including a complete example of showing the credential dialog using the CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials API.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you just want to set the userID: `userID = new StringBuilder("Greg")`

There is an implementation of a wrapper in c# here: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4693/using-the-credential-management-api/

You will probably want the username from `Environment.UserName`.

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't "Remember Password" if the UserName is set.  I've uploaded a sample application to https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxSAZ9JlU2w9VHZWWFBjVEhTNG02N1Q4WkFrUkhDUQ if you'd like to see it in action.